# select / drop does not really drop the column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I think I don't undestand how select or drop are working.
I am exploding a dataset and I don't want some of the columns to be copied to the newly generated entries.

```
val ds = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      ("2017-01-01 06:15:00", "ASC_a", "1"),
      ("2017-01-01 06:19:00", "start", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 06:22:00", "ASC_b", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 06:30:00", "end", "2"),
      ("2017-01-01 10:45:00", "ASC_a", "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 10:50:00", "start", "3"),
      ("2017-01-01 11:22:00", "ASC_c", "4"),
      ("2017-01-01 11:31:00", "end", "5" )
    )).toDF("timestamp", "status", "msg")
    ds.show()

    val foo = ds.select($"timestamp", $"msg")
    val bar = ds.drop($"status")
    foo.printSchema()
    bar.printSchema()
    println("foo " + foo.where($"status" === "end").count)
    println("bar" + bar.where($"status" === "end").count)
```

Output:

> ```
> root
>  |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
>  |-- msg: string (nullable = true)
>
> root
>  |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
>  |-- msg: string (nullable = true)
> ```
>
> foo 2
>   bar 2

Why do I still get an output of 2 for both though I
 a) did not select status
 b) dropped status

EDIT:
`println("foo " + foo.where(foo.col("status") === "end").count)` says that there is no column status. Should this not be the same as `println("foo " + foo.where($"status" === "end").count)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I still get an output of 2 for both

Because optimizer is free to reorganize the execution plan. In fact if you check it:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [_1#4 AS timestamp#8, _3#6 AS msg#10]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(_2#5) && (_2#5 = end))
   +- *SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._1, true) AS _1#4, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._2, true) AS _2#5, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._3, true) AS _3#6]
      +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#3]
```

you'll see that filter is pushed down as early as possible and executed before project. So it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT _1 AS timetsatmp, _2 AS msg
FROM ds WHERE _2 IS NOT NULL AND _2 = 'end'
```

Arguably it is a minor bug, and code should be translated as

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT _1 AS timetsatmp, _2 AS msg FROM ds
) WHERE _2 IS NOT NULL AND _2 = 'end'
```

and throw an exception.